# How to show notification when hitting a specific latitude and longitude on Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, notifications

I was able to create a map fragment already. I wonder If I can make my app have the ability to detect if you're within around uhmm, 200 meters of a certain landmark ( lat = 14.650778, long = 121.048117). I wonder if detecting if you are near a landmark is possible and how to implement it by showing a notification. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the GeoFencing functions of Play Services.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Create the notifications with this

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateNotification

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the [distanceBetween](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) or [distanceTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) methods of the `Location` object to find out what is the distance between you desired point and your current position/ clicked location on the map.

and depending on the output, create a notification, you can use this tutorial for notifications:

[Notification Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html)

Comment: what If I want maybe 200m radius around a specific place?

Comment: I don't think you can provide a specific are with some radius, but if you think about it if one point is the center then the distance to another point on the perimeter is exactly the radius.

Comment: oh I see. will get back to you. I'll try your suggestion

Comment: Hey can you please show me a little bit of code? I'm struggling how to start using it. I'm sorry I'm just new to Android.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't a written code for what you are looking to do.